# Replacing rear derailleur on Murray 15 speed - Looking for parts

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur

I have an old Murray Ultra Terrain mountain bike; it's 15 speed and I had trouble re-mounting the rear derailleur to the frame. It's broken now so I'm looking for a replacement but I'm unsure of what would fit. Here's a photo of the other (non-drive side) of the frame.

[image]

From what I understand, the number of gears on the rear cassette, denote the type of derailleur replacement--in my case, 5. Is this correct?

Where can I purchase the best replacement derailleur for this bike? I prefer to order off Amazon but will look at other options.

Here's a photo of the derailleur:
[image]

I lost the original mounting screw and had to use just whatever fit...

Comment: 5 speed is before my time as a cyclist - Is the shiftier indexed or friction? If friction life gets a lot easier.

Comment: 5-speed rears are pretty much interchangeable -- you just need to match the "hanger" where the unit mounts, as there are 3-4 different schemes for that aspect.  In some cases the problem is with the "hanger", and the derailer itself can still be used.  It would be very helpful to see a picture of the broken unit, and the place where it mounts to the rear dropout.

Comment: Worst case, you could use a claw type Tourney 7 speed. Index shifting came out after 5 speed.

Comment: @Batman there were (maybe even still are) BSOs with indexed 5-speed (shimano SIS). I learnt to ride on one. The problem is that these components were from the special not-available-in-shops BSO range.

Comment: A photo of the derailleur side would be far more useful.

Comment: It's unclear what's wrong with the unit you show in the picture.  It does appear to be slightly bent, but that can often be corrected with a wrench.

Comment: Shifter is indexed.

Comment: I'd rather just replace the whole derailleur unit rather than fiddle with it to make it work. I bought this bike used a number of years ago and have replaced a few parts already. Maybe not worth it, but I like the frame and I want to keep it running.

Answer (score 3):

Likely your Murray uses something like a Falcon 5-speed unit:
[image]

Here's an image of the derailer properly mounted:
[image]

Comment: This does look similar to what I have...Where can I find something like this?

Comment: Google "falcon 5-speed derailleur", or simply ask what's in the spare parts bin at your local bike shop.

Answer (score 2):

The derailleur looks fine (though new pictures show it isn't), it is just installed wrong.

The screw that can be seen above the axle in the derailleur photo holds a piece of metal on the other side of the mounting claw. It is what keeps the derailleur in correct position. It should go into the same slot in the frame as the axle. Image search for "claw mount derailleur" shows what it should look like when installed correctly.

EDIT: The new pictures show it's broken. The choices are either to get a new one (eBay has lots of choices under €10) or get any other claw mount derailleur and use it without indexing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the unit shown in OP's image is bent.  The bend appears to be near the top pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the drive side with the derailleur and wheel off.
[image: drive side]
[image: Looks like it's bent here]
Looks like it's bent here

Answer (score 0):

Right there in the middle is where it's obviously broken.

[image: broken derailleur]

I think it's clear I need a new derailleur. Hopefully these pix make it easier to understand what replacement will work. My concern is in finding a derailleur that fits or having to use the old derailleur hanger, which may work. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: On that, you shouldn't have to use the old der hanger, in fact, the pics Daniel put on there are for derailleurs that have the hanger "built in" to the unit, which is what it looks like yours is as well.  Depending on the type of shifter(indexed or friction[Probably friction, 90% of those were on friction set-ups]), this should be a very inexpensive and readily available part.  I'd start with your local bike shop, see what they have.  You'll probably have to ask, components are usually not displayed at shops, as they use them more in repairs than normal sales.

Comment: My only concern is finding a compatible derailleur with hanger. In Daniel's pic, it shows a bike frame with two different holes for the mounting screw. Mine only has one so I need to be sure to get an exact fit. This is probably easier than I'm thinking, but I've never had to replace a derailleur before.

Comment: Those aren't mounting holes for the derailleur.  It should have a "slotted nut" in alloy that slides into the dropout and pinches in place.

Comment: Now I get it...I guess that explains why it was so hard to get working...One of these would probably work, right? https://www.amazon.com/Dcolor-Racing-Bicycle-Silver-Derailleur/dp/B012CM3T92/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1493738170&sr=8-3&keywords=rear+derailleur+5+speed    https://www.amazon.com/Sunlite-Short-Cage-7spd-Derailleur/dp/B001HD8Q4Q/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1493738170&sr=8-1&keywords=rear+derailleur+5+speed

Comment: Yes, either of those would probably be fine for it.  Considering the old one was a "long cage" derailleur, I'd probably pick the first of those, it looks like a long cage.  Or maybe more like https://www.amazon.com/Sunlite-Long-Cage-7spd-Derailleur/dp/B000BMUD7W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1493743549&sr=8-1&keywords=sunlite+long+cage+rear+derailleur

Comment: Now will these shifters work okay with this new derailleur setup? https://www.amazon.com/Sunrace-Mount-Friction-Shift-Lever/dp/B000A6BBU2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1493739019&sr=8-1&keywords=bike+shifter+index+5+speed

Comment: I'd say those are probably a good fit for that.  Also, please take all this advice with a grain of uncertainty.   As a mechanic and shop rat, I'm used to having hands on a bike to fix it and recommend parts.  Doing it online is a bit less accurate, as there may be something I would see in person that may point it one way or another that I'm missing on the internet.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot though. Being on here has given me the head start to finish this project.